# Approximating marker coordinates by rounding

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have 2 markers with the same coordinates, so I'm trying to approximate their coordinates so that they both display. I have the following code that does not seem to work. Strange thing is that in the browser console I do not even see any errors. Nothing, but no marker displays at all.

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var item = locations[i];
    var a = 0.01;
    var newLat = item[1] + -.00004 * Math.cos((+a*i) / 180 * Math.PI);  // x
    var newLng = item[2] + -.00004 * Math.sin((+a*i) / 180 * Math.PI);  // Y
    var finalLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: finalLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: item[0],
        link: item[3],
        address: item[5],
        phone: item[6],
        mobile: item[7],
        website: item[8],
        image: item[9],
        readmore: item[10],
        icon: item[11],
        type: item[12],
        infoWindowIndex: i
    });

    marker.category = locations[i][12];
    gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {

        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

        // prevent ghost clicks on ipad
        infoBox.setContent('<div class="marker-wrapper animated fadeInDown"><div class="marker-title"> <a href="'+ this.link +'">'+ this.title +'</a> </div><div class="marker-content"><div class="two_third popup-content"><ul>'+ this.address +''+ this.phone +''+ this.mobile +''+ this.website +'</ul></div>'+ this.image +''+ this.readmore +'<div class="clearboth"></div> <div class="close" onClick=\'javascript:infoBox.close();\'><span class="icon-cancel"></span></div></div><span class="icon-down-dir"></span></div>');

        infoBox.open(map, this);
        map.setCenter(this.position);
        map.panTo(this.position);


    }); // end click even
} //end for
```

Some other info:
I'm using JSON to grab the markers info
I'm using MarkerClusterer for clusters.

I have also tried editing the code this way by passing a new var to the position parameter and I get the error `**Uncaught InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object**`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var item = locations[i];

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item[1], item[2] );

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng + (Math.random() -.5) / 1500,
        map: map,
        title: item[0],
        link: item[3],
        address: item[5],
        phone: item[6],
        mobile: item[7],
        website: item[8],
        image: item[9],
        readmore: item[10],
        icon: item[11],
        type: item[12],
        infoWindowIndex: i
    });

    marker.category = locations[i][12];
    gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {

        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

        // prevent ghost clicks on ipad
        infoBox.setContent('<div class="marker-wrapper animated fadeInDown"><div class="marker-title"> <a href="'+ this.link +'">'+ this.title +'</a> </div><div class="marker-content"><div class="two_third popup-content"><ul>'+ this.address +''+ this.phone +''+ this.mobile +''+ this.website +'</ul></div>'+ this.image +''+ this.readmore +'<div class="clearboth"></div> <div class="close" onClick=\'javascript:infoBox.close();\'><span class="icon-cancel"></span></div></div><span class="icon-down-dir"></span></div>');

        infoBox.open(map, this);
        map.setCenter(this.position);
        map.panTo(this.position);


    }); // end click even
} //end for
```

Any clue how to fix this issue?

Comment: I suggest looking at the spidifier plugin (https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier), demo here: http://jawj.github.com/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html - the spidifier plugn also plays well with the markerclusterer plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work:

```
   position: myLatLng + (Math.random() -.5) / 1500,
```

myLatLng is a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), you can't add a number to it, this might work (not tested):

```
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng.lat() + (Math.random() -.5) / 1500,
                                    myLatLng.lng() + (Math.random() -.5) / 1500),
```

Comment: This worked thank you so much, i had missed that part of the documentation :) oh, i'm also a fan of your website there's so many tutorial, all very useful.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

To add the marker to a map is a simple process.

- First you have to have the map instance, I don't see that in your code, maybe it is before the code. It looks like:

  `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);`
- Maybe sounds silly, but you have to be sure these piece of code is being executed, either you executed inside an initialization process, or if you fired through an event.
- The other thing is can you check the result of your calculation of latitude and longitude, just to be sure those numbers are inside the valid range.
- Also the constructor for the google LatLng object is LatLng(double,double), so be sure you are not passing an object or even a string, it should looks like:

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);